# Navigating to different page instead of Ajax call

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms, jsonresponse

I am trying to save a form via ajax as I don't want to reload the page. It is working not completely but it is updating the data except the image or video or any upload file we give.

but after updating it is coming back to the ajax page but the url is diiferent and success message is coming on that page.

I am sharing some of the logic but if more information is required, please let me know .

js code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contentdataform').submit(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'updatecontent', 
            success: function() { 
                mess("Success"); //mess is a function to generate a disappearing message box.
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function updatecontentform(){
    console.log('starting');
    document.getElementById('contentdataform').submit();
}
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def updatecontent(request):
    print("--------------------")
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = request.session['content_id']
        fm = ContentForm(request.POST, instance= Content.objects.get(pk = id))
        print("fm")
        print(fm)
        if fm.is_valid:
            print("valid form")
            form = fm.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
        else:
            print("Not Valid")
    return JsonResponse("Success", safe= False)
```

the output should be the message on the same page but it is reflecting on the new page with url '127.0.0.1:8000/updatecontent'
[image]

Comment: check the `url` attribute in your `ajax` request. you have set it as `'/updatecontent'`.

Comment: @Abhyudai I have set as `url: 'updatecontent'` . I am not able to understand what you saving